# How to install Ubuntu on a Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN with an AMD APU

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I placed an order for Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN (AMD A8 Version) which I will receive soon. This model comes with 750GB HDD (Single Partition) & has Win 7 Home Premium x64 preloaded. I want to create 2 new partitions of 100GB each & install Ubuntu 12.10 & Backtrack 5 R3. I never used an AMD APU based machine before & I heard that installing linux in AMD APU system is not an easy task. I would be very grateful if experts here mention the steps involved in installing both these OS in AMD APU laptop.

Thankyou.

@iSeth Thanks but the link you shared has nothing about installing ubuntu in amd apu laptop. AFAIK one needs to change some settings in bios or tweak bootloader.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/44179

Comment: What makes you think installing Ubuntu on AMD APU is any different from standard installation?

Comment: +bbaja42.  I've installed multiple versions of Ubuntu on my HP dm1z machine, which has an AMD APU, and I've had no problems partitioning my disks or installing the OS next to Win7.

Comment: An AMD APU is the same as an Intel CoreiX processor, they're both X86-64 chips, they're not different in terms of Installation than any other CPU previously released.

Comment: If its so easy then why this user faced this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176803/ubuntu-12-04-wont-boot-on-toshiba-satellite-l855